# Excel VBA Error 1004 only when running without breaking points

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that processes multiple excel workbooks by creating charts in every one of them. It works well on my computer.

When I try to run it on a different computer, it gives me the 1004 error. However, when I put a breaking point on a certain line, the macro runs well. I just have to press F5 for every worksheet:

```
Dim c As Chart
Set c = Charts.add
c.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
c.SetSourceData source:=Sheets("Data Tables").Range("D4:D9, G4:G9"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

The last line is the one I put the break point on. When I do that, no error appears!

Update: This line works for some reason
c.SetSourceData source:=Sheets("Data Tables").Range("D4:D9"), PlotBy:=xlColumns

Comment: You might check if the other computer has an add-in or personal macro workbook installed that your computer doesn't.  Sometimes these macros have event triggers that can fire off, messing up your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem for some reason!
c.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Data Tables").Range("D4:D9")
c.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("Data Tables").Range("G4:G9")